How to remove blank spaces in a jsPDF PDF when exporting a div from GrapesJS in React.js?
I am having an issue when exporting PDF content created with GrapesJS. There are blank spaces at the top of the page, and I have been struggling to find a solution for quite some time without success. Please help me...
My pages:
enter image description here
Result:
enter image description here
My code :
enter image description here
enter image description here

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
